# What's a greeting?

Tags: word-meaning

I have found conflicting information on the definition of greeting. I'm studying a book called "Speed up English" that says that "goodbye", "see you later" and "thank you" are greetings. I thought that greetings were only used to welcome someone or acknowledge their presence such as "hello", "good morning".

"Bye" and "see you later" would be parting phrases, not greetings.

And "thank you" is a sentence, short for "I thank you."

After all, are greetings used to say "hello" and "bye" or just "hello"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're worrying too much. Yes, we 'greet' someone when we meet, not when we leave. We probably 'farewell' them when we leave, so maybe this book should say that 'goodbye' etc are 'farewells' ("Time to say our farewells"). (Informally, they are 'goodbyes' ("Time to say our goodbyes").) Together, 'greetings' and 'farewells' are probably 'salutations', but it would be rare to call them that.

Note that in some languages, people can say the same thing when they meet and leave. In English, we can (perhaps more formally) say 'Good day' as a greeting or farewell. Less formally, I can think of Italian ciao, Korean annyeong and Hawaiian aloha.

Comment: In English "Good evening" is one of the few that can be used as either a greeting or a farewell.

Comment: The Italian _Buona sera_, equivalent to _Good evening_, is used either as greeting or farewell too.